# Error in importing PyGTK: Not able to use GUI in Docker Container

Tags: server, ssh, docker, pygtk, mir

I am working on remote server using SSH. I am running Docker Container in the Server. In the Container I have PyGTK and when I tried importing it using

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi
>>> gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
```

It is giving me following error..

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Due to this I am not able to open GUI. My aim is to record screen.

Any help would be nice. Can I try `xhost`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I tried multiple things including port forwarding. Nothing worked. It's issue with docker.